# Linebreaks removed by pandoc

Tags: html, markdown, line-breaks, pandoc

I am using pandoc to translate from html to markdown.
Pandoc is removing linebreak in the results.

Here is the command I am using:

```
pandoc -f html -t markdown_phpextra myfile.html
```

Is there any way for keeping all the linebreaks in the html file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer pandoc versions support `--wrap=preserve`.

### Old answer:

Pandoc does not distinguish between newlines and other whitespace (outside of `<pre>` tags), since these are not semantically different in HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Digging up an old question since I just discovered that
you can specify a Pandoc extension for this:

```
pandoc -f markdown+hard_line_breaks -t html myfile.html
```

That worked for me (notice that I used regular markdown, though). See also pandoc's man page for further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` tags wherever whitespace needs to be preserved. Have you tried `&nbsp` or `<br>`

Comment: Thanks but I cannot add tage in all the files I want to translate. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I did what to replace each newline with `<p></p>` string with additional `<p>` and `</p>` at the beginning and end. Then I passed the text to pandoc. It worked well.